# Seeking GIS data on military activity in UK, i.e. low flying zones, military practice areas, etc?

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I'm trying to source shapefiles of low flying zones, military aerodromes, military practice areas for the Wales area including offshore in the 12nm limit and EEZ.

Where could I source this information?

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is the place that I recommend researching/asking this.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap contains a lot of military GIS data https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:military. Check out https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data for how to access data from OSM.